# Get the username that runs the executing AppPool

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf

In ASP.NET or WCF is it safe to use `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name`to get the current username that executes the current thread?

I want to ensure that the correct user is impersonated in my WCF Service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

is probably a better alternative, as I don't think that `ServiceSecurityContext.Current` is available in ASP.NET.

You may also want to consider

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
```

if you care about the *user* instead of the process identity.

Comment: The Weird thing is that when I create a file, the owner is "Administrators", which is Very weird because when I use windows authentication with impersonation rather than forms authentication with impersonation, the owner is the domain user that I am logged in as. But both of the Above tells me the correct username. Are you sure that these are the "final"/"only" credentials AppPool is executed with?